# IDA Pro previous function

Tags: disassembly, ida

I'm in the Graph View mode of IDA Pro and I'm looking at a function. This function calls another function, and when I click on that function name, I'm taken to its assembler code.

My problem is that I want a simple way to get back to the function I came from, the caller function. I can do it with jump to xref to but I was hoping for a simpler "go back" or something (like Eclipse has). Is there such a feature available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esc key, or navigation buttons on the toolbar.

Comment: It dissapears from the toolbar while debugging so that's probably why I missed it.  View , toolbars , navigation , jumps activates it though.                                                                Thanks , this answers my questions and it's easier for me to use IDA Pro now.